# why bit-fields for same data types have less in size compared to bit-fields for mix-data types

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

I am curious to know why bit fields with same data type takes less size than with mixed 
data types.

```
struct xyz 
{ 
  int x : 1; 
  int y : 1; 
  int z : 1; 
}; 


struct abc 
{ 
  char x : 1; 
  int y : 1; 
  bool z : 1; 
};
```

sizeof(xyz) = 4
sizeof(abc) = 12.

I am using VS 2005, 64bit x86 machine.

A bit machine/compiler level answer would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alignment.

Your compiler is going to align variables in a way that makes sense for your architecture. In your case, `char`, `int`, and `bool` are different sizes, so it will go by that information rather than your bit field hints.

There was some discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-does-the-sizeof-operator-return-a-size-larger-for-a-structure-than-the-tota) on the matter.

The solution is to give `#pragma` directives or `__attributes__` to your compiler to instruct it to ignore alignment optimizations.

Comment: Note that bit fields don't really have alignment requirements, though.

Comment: No, but the compiler is under no obligation to pack them.

Comment: See ISO14882:2003, §9.6, paragraph 1.

Comment: Another reason why learning about machine architecture and compiler construction is still useful to programmers, in spite of the denials of same by some on SO.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard (1999 version, §6.7.2.1, page 102, point 10) says this:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a 
>   bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another 
>   bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.

There does not seem to be any wording to allow the packing to be affected by the types of the fields. Thus I would conclude that this is a compiler bug.

gcc makes a 4 byte struct in either case, on both a 32-bit and a 64-bit machine, under Linux. I don't have VS and can't test that.

Comment: C++03, §9.6, paragraph 1 says, "Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit." It seems mahesh is using a C++ compiler.

Comment: On the other hand, he also tagged this as a C question, not just C++. I guess the answer is different for C and C++.

Comment: I would be wary of claiming this as a "bug" since you were quoting from the ISO C99 standard.  MSVC++ makes no claim of adherence to C99.  It supports ISO C90/ANSI C89.

Comment: PS: The use of types other than int or unsigned in bit-fields is an extension with respect to C89/90 so all bets are off with respect to behaviour.

Comment: If MSVC++ doesn't support a decade old standard... it doesn't sound very impressive, does it?

Comment: @greyfade important remark referencing the standard.
In practice, msvc seems to always allocate the first variable of a different type, unlike gcc and clang. eg: { uint16_t a : 14; uint8_t x : 2; } will return sizeof 4 / 2 / 2  for msvc / gcc / clang

Answer (score 0):

It's complier bug or some code error.
All bits assigned in the structure always try to make sizeof highest data type defined.
e.g. In struct xyz sizeof highest data type is 4 i.e. of int.
In the similar fashion for second structure abc highest data type size is 4 for int.

Where as if we change variables of structure as following:
    struct abc
    {
     char a:1;
     char b:1;
     bool c:1;
    };

sizeof(abc) would be 1 not 4. Since size highest data type is 1 and all bits fit into 1byte of char.

various tests could be performed by changing data type in the structure.

Link for output based on old structure:
Visit http://codepad.org/6j5z2CEX

Link for output based on above structure defined by me:
Visit http://codepad.org/fqF9Ob8W

To avoid such problems for sizeof structures we shall properly pack structures using #pragma pack macro.